# How to handle Spree::Shipping error in Spree 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I was trying to rescue Spree::Shipping Error. What happens is , if any fedex Api doesn't give proper response , user stuck on "address" state. He can't move forword.

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't able to progress past the address state, the correct behaviour is to not allow the user forward.  If a user can't enter their address, you can't determine what the shipping cost should be, and therefore can't bill the user the correct amount.  Allowing the user past this stage is dangerous.

You can customize the flow of the checkout by using the [Checkout Flow Customization Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html).  However, this is a bad idea.  Your best bet would be to figure out what the error from the FedEx API is, tell the user if it's something that they can correct, and error out if it's something that they can't correct.

Comment: Thanks for reply and I agree with you what you said

Let me explain you the scenario .. i am using 3 different shipping Services.
1. First Class Mail
2. USPS Priority
3. FedEx

Now what happens is, If FedEx is not responding for any ZIP CODE , User stuck on Address state only. Even though for same ZIP CODE USPS Priority responds with rate_hash. What I want is if any ZIP CODE not getting response from FedEx then User Should be able to move on Next State("Delivery") with Other Shipping Methods (i.e. USPS, First Class Mail). And FedEx Services should hide.

Comment: Your best bet will be to change where you're rescuing the shipping error.  Check the stack trace of your exception and find where the FexEx shipping method is being added to the list of available shipping methods.  Rescue the exception there, and don't add it to the list of available shipping methods.  Then allow the user to proceed through using only the other shipping methods.